# Editing a WordPress plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to edit a WordPress plugin. My conventional thinking is telling me to edit HTML but I know WordPress is PHP. I'm **not** talking about CSS editing either (aesthetics, positioning, color...etc). I know how to do that.

For example let's say I have a plugin Form with an input box with the title "how much" however I want it to say something else like "Dollars"....how do I do this?

Also the plugin admin area doesn't give me the option to change this in the backend. Isn't there another way to change that?

Comment: Try and be more specific; the answer would depend on which plugin you are using and what you are trying to change

Comment: Well I already decsribed what I'm trying to change ...the plugin is a classified plugin called AWPCP...however even though I'm a newbie, my question seems to be more of an overall nature of plugin editing and not particular to one specific plugin. Did you even read my initial post? Amazing you mention the word "newbie" and people don't bother carefully reading the post. Need to stop using that word. thanks.

Comment: Well, without any other information all I can suggest is you do a search for "how much" within the plugin file(s) and see what you find.

Answer (score 0):

Ways to do it:

- Search for the string in the plugin's files and check if it offers a [filter hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Filters) (`apply_filters`), if it does [create a plugin or use functions.php](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72160/where-do-i-put-the-code-snippets-i-found-here-or-somewhere-else-on-the-web).
- Use [another plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3578/change-the-text-on-the-publish-button/3675#3675) to modify the string.
- If the plugin has [internatinaliztion support](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers#Translating_Plugins), create a translation file for your language and translate only that string. Use `en_US` if your WPLANG is empty.
- Hack the plugin itself and change the string (bad, this has to be done at each plugin upgrade).